# Fluent NHibernate Row Level Security Implementation - Too Sketchy?

Tags: security, nhibernate, fluent

This filter code works how I want it to (Loads only time tickets related to the currently logged in customer.)  Two things worry me about it:

1. Adding `collate Latin1_General_CI_AS` to the column name.  I've read other places NHibernate doesn't support joining multiple collations, so I'm concerned about what the unintended side effects.
2. `this_1_`:  Will I *always* be able to rely on that table alias being used?

---

```
public class TimeTicketMap : ClassMap<TimeTicket>
    {
        public TimeTicketMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.TicketID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Join("CONTRACTS", x =>
                                   {
                                x.KeyColumn("CONTRACT collate Latin1_General_CI_AS");
                                Id(y => y.JobNumber).Column("Job");
                                x.Map(y => y.Customer);
                            });
            ApplyFilter<CustomerFilter>("this_1_.Customer = :customer");
        }
    }
```

Can an expert in Fluent/NHibernate either talk me out of this, or grimace disapprovingly while telling me I likely won't run into serious problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the collation to the Sql Dialect so it wouldn't get treated as a column, and using an exists filter (Less efficient, but I know I can rely on it.)

```
public class CustomSqlDialect : MsSql2005Dialect
{
    public CustomSqlDialect()
    {
        RegisterKeyword("Latin1_General_CI_AS");
    }
}
```

with

```
mapping.ApplyFilter<CustomerFilter>
    (@"exists (SELECT cont.CUSTOMER FROM CONTRACTS cont 
               WHERE cont.CUSTOMER = :customer 
               AND Job COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS = cont.CONTRACT");
```